# OOPs concepts used in this class

Tags: c#, java, class, oop

Consider a simple class `A`.

```
class A
{
   int id=0;
   public int  getId()
   {
      return this.id++;
   }
}
```

The question was **`What are all the OOPS concepts used in the above class?`**.

I asked to the interviewer, what he meant by OOPS Concepts and the reply was `general OOPS concepts like inheritance, polymorphism, etc, etc.,`

I replied that inheritance is not in the above code (no base class to derive from) and the only answer I could think of at that movement was this:

`variable-hiding` because the private variable `id` is accessible only by the `getId` method.

Is there any thing that you guys catch ?

**EDIT:**

What would be in c# ? In java, we have the default modifier as `internal`. 
Is there any thing that change if the same question was asked for c# ?

Comment: Encapsulation is the only concept I see there

Comment: @user1233963: So, you also mean the variable-hiding thing? (`id` is encapsulated right ?)

Comment: There is no `Encapsulation` here, access modifier of `id` is default.

Comment: Technically, nothing is used here, because `id` is not encapsulated properly (it's not marked `private`).

Comment: Obfuscation: What looks like a simple accessor modifies the object in an unexpected manner. Techniques like this are very important, since they teach maintenance programmers not to make assumptions.

Comment: Question: What are all the OOPS concepts used in the above class?
Can answer be nothing? I couldn't see a oop principle here, too.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Thanks for the comment. Is it a `oops` principle that all the fields should be `private` and only the methods of a class can access them ?

Comment: The principle in play here is encapsulation. OOP does not require the field to be specifically `private` (although in practice that's what it usually is), all it requires is that the access to the field be restricted from outside the class.

Comment: In most OO languages (C# and Java at least), all classes extend some base `Object` by default.  So there's _technically_ inheritance (along with several inherited methods).  I might mention it in an answer, although I'm not sure how much I'd count it if I was asking...  Oh, and it doesn't look like anybody's mentioned it yet, but that "getter" will behave strangely in a multi-threaded context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A better question would have been about all the good programming practice violated.

Take `getId()`, which looks like it's a simple getter, but actually modifies the state of the class. It should have been called `generateId()`; `getNextId()` would have been acceptable.

Encapsulation (yes, the variable-hiding thing) is also violated, because `id` has internal, not private visibility, making it visible to other classes in the same package for no good reason.

Comment: Thanks for the points. An another thing I noted now, is : `getNextId` is not an accepted name because, how many times you called `getId` function, it is going to just return 1

Comment: I have tagged `C#` too, to find out is there anything relevant to that language features. because, in C#, by default, all members of a class are private.

Answer (score 1):

```
class A
{
  private int id=0;
   public int  getId()
   {
      return this.id++;
   }
}
```

Well it has followed nothing but Abstraction as ADT but it has **no encapsulation** unfortunately. we cannot call it as encapsulation when a variable is non-private and it has assessor methods since its not hiding the data. We can say it has followed encapsulation only if it has **private access specifier at the id**.